# Array of object to csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an object of arrays I want to output it in csv format in drupal, 
using this code to output csv:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w'); 
foreach ($records as $key => $object) { 
    fputcsv($fp, $object->data);
}
```

Output in file.csv:

> Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array

Here's the object.

```
Array
(
    [43] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111111
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test@test.com
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [43] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Kim
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11111111
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test@test.com
                        )
        )
)
```

The file.csv should contain the value from the array.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Well, your code works well just as you want. Unless you want something else, but you didn't say

Comment: @Forien the file.csv should contain the value from the array.

Comment: @gabmon the problem lies in your structure, fputcsv expects an array not a multidimensional one. i.e. you access your data through `data[3][0]` instead of just `data[3]`, that's where this Array in your csv gets from.

Answer (score 2):

if your desired output is

```
test,test,1111111,,test@test.com
kim,...
.
.
.
```

Then your data should be like :

```
[43] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [3] => test
                    [4] => test
                    [5] => 11111111
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => test@test.com
                )
        )
```

rearrange your data before using fputcsv